# Golang range type conversion

Tags: go

I'm very confused by this code that I have:

```
docs, ok := foo.([]interface {})
if !ok{ panic("assertion failed") }

fmt.Println("The type of docs: ", reflect.TypeOf(docs))
for _, doc := range docs {
    fmt.Println("Doc Type: ", reflect.TypeOf(doc))
}
```

The output when I run this is:

```
The type of docs: []interface {}
Doc type: bson.D
```

I don't get it.  I type assert foo to  `[]interface{}` and store it in docs.  That works as expected, but then in the loop, the first thing I print out is the type of `doc` and it says it's `bson.D`.  How is it not `interface {}`?? I even changed the name of `doc` to `bar` thinking maybe it was a scoping issue or something, but I get the same results.

Comment: BTW, if you're just going to panic on `!ok` just leave it out and do `docs := foo.([]interface {})`. The one variable version of a type assert panics on its own if the type doesn't match.

Answer (score 3):

[TypeOf documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#TypeOf) says: *TypeOf returns the reflection Type of the value in the interface{}. TypeOf(nil) returns nil.*

So `doc` is of type interface{} but `TypeOf` returns its "true" type.

Comment: But how does it know the 'true' type?  In my case, foo is the `.Value` of a bson.D http://bazaar.launchpad.net/+branch/mgo/v2/view/head:/bson/bson.go#L121 , which is interface{}.  So how does the loop magically know what the values are if I've created a variable that is a []interface{}

Comment: No, the loop doesn't know the type of what's inside `docs`. `doc` is `interface{}`. However, when you use `reflect.TypeOf()`, TypeOf knows it is a interface{} (using reflection) but doesn't print that, but the type of the value inside the interface.

Comment: Go stores both a pointer to the data and a pointer to the meta data when you store an interface{}. It is this meta data that conveys the actual type of the data that interface{} is pointing to. Reflect uses this meta data to return the actual type, also see http://research.swtch.com/interfaces for more information

Comment: But how does it know that it is a bson.D?  The data that could be in Value is coming across the wire and being stored in Value, which is an `interface{}`.  It could be a string, []unit8, bson.D, who knows.  Nobody knows until runtime. This particularly vexing because I want to type assert it to a bson.M, which should be functionally equivalent, but it's telling me that it's a bson.D and panics.

Comment: @FuriousGeorge what is unmarshalling your data?

Comment: @FuriousGeorge The type is only known at runtime indeed. When the function returns an `interface{}` it was already set to `bson.D`, `string`, ... inside that function. It could be anything at compile time, but it's only ever one type at runtime, and you can retrieve the type from the interface meta data. What exactly panics? `doc` inside your loop is `interface{}` at compile time, so you can just type assert it to `bson.M`: `if docM, ok := doc.(bson.M); ok { ... }`

Comment: I think @jmaloney hit it on the head.  I just dug through the lib source, and it was using an Unmarshaller which uses a decoder which creates the elements based on the type that you are unmarshalling into http://bazaar.launchpad.net/+branch/mgo/v2/view/head:/bson/decode.go#L125.   Makes much more sense now.